# Proving that a field isomorphism exists

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I have a question that I need some helping solving:

Show if $G$ is a field with exactly three elements, then there is a field isomorphism $f: \Bbb Z_3 \to G$. Note that $\Bbb Z_3$ is defined $\Bbb Z_3=(\{0,1,2\}, +, .)$ where $x+y=(x+y) \mod 3$ and $xy=xy \mod 3$.

Comment: A field homomorphism preserves $0$ and $1$, so you don't have much choice regarding the mapping. Verify that the mapping is a field homomorphism.

Comment: I don't know what a homomorphism is. I am taking a course in Real Analysis. The tags must have been changed by the editor to abstract-algebra and finite-fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ is a field with three elements, then the elements must be $\{0, 1, \alpha\}$, where $0$ is the additive identity, $1$ is the multiplicative identity, and $\alpha$ is a third element.

- Show that $\alpha = 1 + 1$.
- Define $f : G \to \mathbb{Z}_3$ by $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$, $f(\alpha) = 2$. Show $f$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: I understand the second step. I don't understand why I need to show that alpha= 1+1.

Comment: @JimDarson I suppose you really don't. It just makes showing that $f$ is an isomorphism slightly easier.

Comment: I suppose that, if I'm following your suggestions correctly, that by showing that f: G->Z3 is an isomorphism, then it follows that, since being an isomorphism implies that f contains an inverse, that  the inverse of f is also an isomorphism.

Answer (score 3):

Another answer proceeds by showing that the additive groups are isomorphic and the multiplicative groups are isomorphic.  For the convenience of the readers of this question, here is a counterexample to show that this is not in general sufficient for the fields to be isomorphic.  (Thus in my opinion this other answer is totally bogus.)

Let $F_1 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ and $F_2 = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-11})$.  These are nonisomorphic fields.  However, the additive groups of each one are two dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces, hence are isomorphic.  Each multiplicative group is isomorphic to the direct product of a cyclic group of order $2$ with a free commutative group of countable rank.  This is especially easy to see here since the ring of integers of each of $F_1$ and $F_2$ is a PID, but in fact for any number field $K$, the group $K^{\times}$ is isomorphic to the product of the finite cyclic group of roots of unity in $K$ with a free commutative group of countable rank.

I will also add that in my opinion it is always better to construct an explicit isomorphism than to argue that two structures are isomorphic, if possible.  In the case of a finite field $F$ of prime order $p$, it is not only possible but easy: as for any ring, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow F$.  Since $F$ is finite of order $p$, $\varphi$ is surjective and its kernel is $p\mathbb{Z}$, so $\varphi$ induces an isomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\sim}{\rightarrow} F$.  If now $F_1$ and $F_2$ are two finite fields of order $p$, then $\varphi_2 \circ \varphi_1^{-1}: F_1 \rightarrow F_2$ is an explicit isomorphism.  (Of course this is really just a slightly fancier/cleaner version of the straightforward argument involving $f(1+\ldots+1) = f(1) + \ldots + f(1) = 1 + \ldots + 1$.) It is easy to see that this isomorphism is *unique*.

Comment: Of course, in any "class" of fields whose isomorphism class is determined by their cardinality, having isomorphic additive groups is obviously enough. For example, algebraically closed characteristic zero fields of uncountable cardinality, and, luckily for the OP, finite fields :) +1 btw

Comment: @Alex: with regards to algebraically closed fields, actually my initial example of a pair of fields with isomorphic additive and multiplicative groups which are not isomorphic was the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ and the maximal solvable extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.  But that seemed abstruse compared to the example given above.  It is actually an interesting question to characterize all fields $F$ for which any field $F'$ with additive and multiplicative groups isomorphic to those of $F$ must be isomorphic to $F$.  Yes, this holds for all finite fields (but one still must prove this!).

Comment: I wonder how much harder the problem of "Characterize fields $F$, such that if $R$ is a ring such that $(R,+)\cong (F,+)$ and $F^\times\cong R^\times$, then $R\cong F$". I wonder how close to a field such a ring $R$ must be. For example, $\overline{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times\overline{\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}}$ have isomorphic additive and unit groups, but the latter isn't a field.

Comment: @Alex: maybe you (or I) should ask these as questions here...

Comment: I'd be interested to hear people's answers to these questions, and in general how much information the additive group and unit group of a ring tell you about the ring. You should though, you are way more popular/well-known on the website, and so are more likely to win the upvote popularity contest :)

Comment: You are perfectly convincing that the two isomorphisms do not necessarily create a field isomorphism.  I stand corrrected. (continued)

Comment: Re the field of order 3 there are two choices of isomorphism for each group, but since the field contains both a 0 and 1, then one of those choices fails.  If 0,a,b is the additive group your isomorphs are a+a = 0 (forcing a+b and b+b) or a+b = 0.  When you add the condition that either a or b has to be 1 you are forced into a+a=0 and aa=1 in both cases, even without stating explicitly that 0 $\rightarrow$ 0 and 1 $\rightarrow$ 1. In this case stating the isomorphism explicitly is clearer.  However, dealing only with specifics does not show you what the generalizations might be.

Comment: @alex your comment is helpful and educational

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: I wonder why we cannot establish a isomorphism between given fields by $x+\sqrt{-7}y\mapsto x+\sqrt{-11}y.$

Comment: @Bumblebee: that map does not preserve multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $G$ consists of $-1,0,1$. One idea for verifying this is to assume for the sake of contradiction $1=-1$ and call the remaining element $x$. Then $x=1/x$ so $x+1=x+x^2=x(1+x)$ and either $1+x=0$ or $x=1$, we have a contradiction.

Define $\varphi:\mathbb Z_3\to G$ by $\varphi(i)=i\cdot 1_G$. In your own work, you will have to carefully define $i\cdot g$, where $g\in G$. Check that $\varphi$ is a homomorphism and that it is injective. Since any injective function between finite sets of the same size is a bijection we are done.

Answer (score -1):

A slightly more abstract approach: G and Z<sub>3</sub> are both fields of order 3.  A field is a group both under addition and multiplication.  Now both G and Z<sub>3</sub> have additive subgroups of order 3, and since there is only one group of order 3 (to within isomorphism), it must be that the additive group in G is isomorphic to the additive group in Z<sub>3</sub>. Same with the multiplicative group.So the 2 fields are isomorphic.

What we did here was show there must be an isomorphism without actually constructing it.  One nice consequence of this is that the same proof works for fields of any finite prime order.

Comment: Hold on, you showed that the additive groups are isomorphic and the multiplicative groups are isomorphic, but how do you know you're using the same isomorphism in both cases?

Comment: @ben -- you have a  good point.  I'm pretty sure it's okay because there is only one cyclic group of prime order.  The operation on the group (addition, multiplication, or anything else) shouldn't matter.  But I'll think some more about it.